# Load balancing router required for two 4G dongle based ISP

Tags: load-balancing, router, failover, 4g, wan

I have internet connection at my home using a 4G wifi USB dongle, providing the hotspot. Since the service is not always good, I also use a second 4G USB dongle (with sim of a different service provider), when the first connection is down.

I, ideally, want a wifi router, which would take two 4G USB sticks as input, and in turn provide one single wifi network, with the two 4G connections as the backend. The objective is to get seamless internet connectivity (without having to discover internet failure the hard way and without manually switching to the second network).

Are such dual WAN (or whatever they may be called) routers available in the market? Would a `Cisco RV320` be a close match to my requirement? In case, there are dual WAN routers available, but with ethernet port instead of USB port, is there an easy way to convert 4G USB dongle to ethernet RJ45 and then use in the router? I am located in India and if the solution is available at Amazon, receiving such link would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is usually termed 'bonding' of internet channels.

It is a common technique to either get higher bandwidth than is otherwise available or to counter availability issues on any one link.

If you search for 'Internet bonding' services or routers you will find examples - e.g.:

- https://www.wiredbroadcast.com/products.html#card-mediaport
- http://simplybonding.com/examples/mobile-video-streaming.html

Comment: Thanks Mick. Seems like there are no routers with two 4G sim/USB with failover in the Indian market. There are many with one ethernet and one USB port for failover.